# preg_match to allow specific special characters in string

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can i achieve that password have (backward slash,forward slash,single quote,double quotes) then and then only it will not allow else it will return true using custom validation.i don't have much idea about preg_match so all suggestions are acceptable.

I have tried below code to achieve that but can't get success.

So anyone have some suggestions/idea ?

php code :

```
    public function check_password($str){
        return ( !preg_match("/^[a-z0-9!@#$%^&*()_-+|;:<>,.?]+$/i", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
    }
```

if i will put exclude(backward slash,forward slash,single quote,double quotes) then it must allow me to store password in database

For example :

```
Password  : !@#$%^&*()_-+| ;:<>, // true
Password  : /12345               //false
Password  : 1Aa3!@#$%^&*()_-+| ;:<> //true(here white space also allowed)
```

Comment: You only want to test for exactly those characters you are insisting on. So something like `'/[\\\/\'"]/'`. you do _not_ want things like `a-z0-9` in there, since that would satisfy the test even without any more exotic characters.

Comment: @arkascha Thanks for reply

Comment: so how can i achive that because i have tried with '/[\\\/\'"]/' but its not working :(

Comment: And "its not working" means what _exactly_?

Comment: I have tried this code but its allowing (backward slash,forward slash)
public function check_password($str){
  return ( preg_match('/[\\\/\'"]/', $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
 }

Comment: That is what I understood from your question: that you _want to_ accept or insist in such characters in your password. Insisting on more complex characters in passwords does make sense from a security point of view. If I got that wrong, then _please_ take the time to rephrase your question so that it is less vague and clearly defines what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: Let users type their passwords the way they want, don't limit them to what you want, if a user want a sentence password with letters only let him.

Comment: @arkascha Thanks for reply but i do not want to allow (backward slash,forward slash,single quote,double quotes) in password rest of any characters(inc. special characters) are allowed. That's i need

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile actually that's application needs in which i cant change

Comment: But why on earth would you want to limit the characters used in passwords? Thats insane! _why_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand you want only this characters - backward slash,forward slash,single quote,double quotes to be **disabled** for you password validation. So here is the code:

```
 public function check_password($str){
    return ( preg_match('/^[^\\\"\'\/]+$/i', $str));
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Fixed.

Comment: its return true for password /12345 instead of false

Comment: Thanks for reply but still its not work in my case it returns true for /12345 instead of false

Comment: it should return you 0. You copied the whole code, right?

Comment: would you accept one of the answers so the question not remain unanswered?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
public function check_password($str){
 return (!preg_match('/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%]{8,12}$/', $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
}
```

Comment: if i am going to store password with  !@#$%^&*()_-+| ;:<>, then throws false instead of true

Comment: Just remove & try with `!` operator.